# Ajax -How to Fetch data

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax

I am stuck on trying to fetch data using AjAX. Below is the code for a HTML form that has an input value. The data value gets pushed to a python handler via a submit button. On the server side, the python handler stores the data in the database.

Now I need to fetch the data from the database first via AJAX and display if there is an existing value. The data consists of a "yes or no" status, so pretty simple. But I don't know how to fetch the data using ajax, and properly set the input value based on data fetched. The question, how would I call a handler via Ajax to return a value?

```html
<html>
<script language="javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

send_data = function(status) {

    $.ajax({
            url: "/Subscription",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {'status' : status},
            type: "POST",
            cache: false

    }).done(function(data, status, xml) {

         var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
         alert(obj.success);

    }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

    }).always(function() {

    });

}


$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#subscription").submit(function() {
    send_data($("#switch-1").prop('checked') ? 'yes' : 'no');
      return false;
  });

});
</script>

</head>
<body>
 
<form id="subscription" action="" method="post">
    <label  class="mdl-switch mdl-js-switch mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="switch-1">
    <input type="checkbox" id="switch-1" class="mdl-switch__input" id="status" name="status" />
    <span class="mdl-switch__label">blemtorp@google.com subscription status is: << subscription >> </span>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" /></label>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks so much. Any hints will be so helpful.

Answer (score 0):

To perform an asynchronous call based on user input, you have to make the request and then explicitly specify which actions you want to perform in the request is successful, fails, etc.

For example:

```
function send_data(shouldRequest, successCallback) {

  // if ...prop('checked'), run ajax request
  if (shouldRequest) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "/Subscription",
      dataType: "json",
      data: {'status' : status},
      type: "POST",
      cache: false
    }).done(function(data, status, xml) {

      // when request completes, run callback function
      successCallback(data);
    });
  }

}

$("#subscription").submit(function() {
  var checked = $("#switch-1").prop('checked');

  var successCallback = function(data) {
    // perform success actions on data here
  }

  send_data(checked, successCallback);
});
```

If you pass `successCallback` to the `send_data` function, you can run the function *only when the asynchronous call has successfully completed*. You can also pass in other functions to handle errors, etc.

You can additionally pass in other functions to handle different results from your ajax request, like a function to handle errors.

Comment: Thank you Himmel and also Peter for your advice.  I was able to successfully set the state of the status. I ended up modifying the javascript to use the Material Design Light Switch (using the input statement), and that set the correct state.  Also, there was a bug having "return false;" in the newly changed click function. Thanks so much for both your advice.

Answer (score 0):

By setting `dataType:"json"` in ajax there is no need to use `JSON.parse()` on `done()` callback.

Use `data.success` or `data.status` depending on your json.

Example json response
`{'success':'yes'}` or `{'status':'yes'}`